# Generate sequence number with the prefix of current year For Example: 2016-000001- PHP / MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to generate the sequence of number starting from 000001 (total six digits) with the prefix of the current year. And then store it into the database. 
The format will be like this: year-000001.
**For example:** 2016-000001

And when the year will changed then the sequence of number will automatically reset to 000001.
**For example:** 2017-000001

Comment: Check out the `date()` and `str_pad()` functions, or `for` and `str_pad()`

Comment: @Blake how to generate the sequence of 000001?

Comment: @Blake thanks dear I got it.

Comment: Just store the year in one column and an integer in another column, and leave it at that. If you use MyISAM, you can set to restart at 1 when the year changes - but I'm not sure that that's a good enough reason for using MyISAM

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you accept one or leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

By using `date()` and `str_pad()` you can generate the sequence like 2016-000001

```
$year= date('Y');
$year=$year.'-';
$n=0;
$n = str_pad($n + 1, 6, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
$number=$year.$n;
echo $number;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have retrieved the last assigned number from the database, and need to generate the next in PHP, you can use this function:

```
function getNextNumber($id = '') {
    $year = date('Y');
    $seq = $year <> +$id ? 0 : +substr($id, -6);
    return sprintf("%0+4u-%0+6u", $year, $seq+1);
}

// Example calls (in 2016):
$id = getNextNumber('2016-023000'); // 2016-023001  
$id = getNextNumber('2015-193481'); // 2016-000001
```

The first time, you just pass the empty string, or nothing at all:

```
$id = getNextNumber(); // 2016-000001
```